# Where is the code for the Bootloader stored in an Android phone?

Tags: bootloader

Where is the bootloader program on an Android phone stored ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The boot-loader code is stored within the `/boot` partition. Majority of Android handsets uses the Qualcomm's Boot Loader, called LK (Little Kernel), barring Samsung, which uses their own form of boot-code.

LK has the following:

- Variety of nand devices for bootup
- USB driver to enable upgrading images over usb during development
- Keypad driver to enable developers enter ‘fastboot’ mode for image upgrades
- Display driver for debugging and splash screen
- Enable Android recovery image and image upgrades

**This applies to only, Qualcomm chipsets hence the exemption of Samsung based handsets**

There is a website blog that cites this from [source](https://www.codeaurora.org/2010/03/02/little-kernel-based-android-bootloader/)

The actual source code, if anyone is curious enough, can be found on CodeAurora site. This is known as CAF, in which a lot of Qualcomm specific code for kernels can be found in.

***As a side-note***: Google releases source to AOSP, CAF, pulls from them, modifies it to make it fit within Qualcomm chipsets, then the Manufacturers pull those down and add their own bits, it is that for the reason there's, AOSP, CAF and CyanogenMod that are the main three flavours of Android.

The actual source code to the boot-loader can be found [on CAF's git repository](https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=kernel/lk.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/eclair;hb=refs/heads/eclair), and has not changed much, it can also be found in CyanogenMod's source, specifically in, `/bootable/bootloader` also.

Comment: Do you know if CAF/LK would have been used for the nVidia chipset Nexus 7 (2012)?

Comment: @Greg have no idea as I have never owned a Nexus 7, nVidia - But having said that - there is AOSP sources available to download - might be worthwhile to do a repo sync and build the sources for the [nakasi](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasi) device, you will learn so much out of that.

Comment: What's the difference between [aboot](https://source.codeaurora.org/external/gigabyte/kernel/lk/tree/app/aboot?h=LA.BR.1.2.7-05910-8x09.0) and booloader (LK) ? Why is there a separate partition called `/aboot` in my device, instead of being in `/boot` itself?

Comment: Is the AOSP stock bootloader available open source? I pulled AOSP and `bootable/` contains only `recovery/`, not `bootloader/`.